# What is master key vulnerability in android?

Tags: security, malware

What is master key vulnerability in Android? From looking at a few different sites, I understand that it is bypassing the authentication provided by signing of apps.

How can I detect an app is vulnerable to master key vulnerability. Can anybody please give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You've already described correctly what that "master key vulnerability" is about. If your only source for new apps is *Google Play*, you're most likely on the safe side; danger from this seems to be restricted to [side-loading](/questions/tagged/side-loading) via [unknown-sources](/questions/tagged/unknown-sources).

However: If you want to check whether your device is affected, there are several apps out there which promise to do this. E.g. [Belarc Security Advisor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Belarc-Security-Advisor/com.belarc.securityadvisor) describes itself as checking for several hundred security flaws known on Android (including the *master key*). If the check is "positive", there are also fixes available, like [Master Key dual fix](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Master-Key-dual-fix/tungstwenty.xposed.masterkeydualfix) or the [Master-Key Security Patch](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.oasisfeng.security.masterkeypatch) (a module for the Xposed framework).