# How i can protect my android from Master Key Vulneralability?

Tags: security

When i install apps ,that i take from my friends , it seems quite fishy , so how to check that the apps are trusted or not.

Comment: See also: [What is master key vulnerability in android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/58579/16575)

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether your device is affected using e.g. [Bluebox Security Scanner](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Bluebox-Security-Scanner/com.bluebox.labs.onerootscanner).

To close the vulnerability, your device needs root access. If that pre-condition is given, there are different fixes available, e.g.

- [Master Key dual fix](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Master-Key-dual-fix/tungstwenty.xposed.masterkeydualfix) (a module for the [xposed-framework](/questions/tagged/xposed-framework))
- [Master-Key Security Patch](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.oasisfeng.security.masterkeypatch) (again a module for *Xposed*)
- [ReKey](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ReKey-for-rooted-phones/io.rekey.rekey) (a stand-alone app)